# Hibernate bidirectional self referencing @OneToOne relation fetching

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, lazy-loading, one-to-one, bidirectional

My projet use springboot2, Hibernate 5.4 and enableLazyInitialization of byte code enhancement is enabled

I have this model where my entity is in relation with another "new" entity of the same type through a bidirectional @OneToOne.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    private id
    private A new;
    private A old;
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_new")
    public A getNew() {
        return new;
    }

    public void setNew(final A new) {
        this.new = new;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "new", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST},
              orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    public A getOld() {
        return old;
    }

    public void setOld(final A old) {
        this.old = old;
    }
    
}
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to fetch both ends of the relation when I'm querying a list of A, to avoid the n+1 requests of a classic lazy load.

For example if I'm using spring's entitygraph annotation this way, "new.old" won't be fetched.

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"new", "new.old"})

    ...
    from A a0_
         left outer join A a1_ on a0_.id_new = a1_.id
         left outer join A a2_ on a1_.id = a1_.id_new
    ...
```

So right now my relation "new"->"old" is loaded with n+1 requests and I'm looking for a way to optimise it.
But since my relation is a @OneToOne I don't have access to @BatchSize or @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) to load multiple "old" for a page of "A"s.

To my knowledge there isn't something like an Hibernate.initialize(List listA, String property); or a query who would fill missing relations of objects already in the persistence context.

I'm also wondering if in fact it would be better if I dropped the biderectional relation in favor of a 2 uniderectional ones with a new "id_old" fk column for my "old" relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a Hibernate bug, so please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Having said that, I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(A.class)
public interface ADto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    ANewDto getNew();

    @EntityView(A.class)
    interface ANewDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        AOldDto getOld();
    }
    @EntityView(A.class)
    interface AOldDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ADto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ADto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<ADto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Comment: Thanks for answering!, I didn't know about Blaze-Persistence but I sure will check it out. If I have some spare time I will also make a reproductible use case like you adviced. In the mean time I dropped the birectionnal relationship in favor of 2 unidrectionnal ones since adding another fk weren't an issue.